# CSS relative position left works, but top doesn't

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position arbitrary elements arbitrarily within an arbitrary container. I want to specify a position as a percentage where

- `0%` means "left edge aligned with the left of the container,"
- `100%` means "right edge aligned with the right of the container,"
- Any value in between is linearly interpolated, so `50%` would be "middle aligned with middle"

To achieve this, the container has `position: relative;`. The element has `position: absolute;` with `left` and `top` equal to the percentages - these percentages will be relative to the container's size. Then, the element's contents are shifted back with `position: relative;` and `left` and `top` equal to negative the percentage, as this will be relative to the element's size.

Demo:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
#item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 80%;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
#item>img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: -80%;
  top: -80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In the demo, the green box is the container, the red box is the element's "real" position, while the placeholder image is the actual content. The coordinate used here is `(80%,80%)` making it appear in the lower-right corner.

As you can see, the `left` component works absolutely fine. It is exactly where it should be. The `top`, however, is not doing the "shift back" thing. It's not moving at all.

Of course there are many similar questions, but all of the ones I've seen stem from the "relative to" element being the `relative` one, not the `absolute`, which meant the container had zero height - fair enough. Indeed, explicitly setting the `height` on my red box in the demo fixes the issue. However, did I mention how arbitrary these components are? I cannot explicitly set the height of the element, I need it to vary based on the content, which may change dynamically.

Any ideas how I might go about this?

Comment: Seems like when there is an offset in ```px``` everything works fine

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance Makes sense, but I can't use `px` in this situation due to a need for responsiveness. In the "real thing", the container has `max-width: 600px; width: 100%` and an aspect ratio spacer.

Comment: could you use `transform: translateY(-80%)` on the image? Conceptually this is different from `left` but in your specific example should be the same thing

Comment: @fcalderan While I would love such a simple solution, unfortunately I cannot do that as `transform` does not round to the nearest pixel like `position` does, and this results in blurry borders and/or images. Since the images are pixel sprites, this is unacceptable in this case.

Comment: and what about `margin-top: -80%`? This would collapse the container but you could set an height

Comment: @fcalderan `margin-top: <percentage>` is, unfortunately, relative to the *width* and not the height.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol absolutely, but your image is squared so it's just a trick :)

Comment: Again, "arbitrary" :p It's square in the example, it (usually) won't be.

Comment: to be clear, you want the image to behave like a background image specified with background position and % values ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That would be a good way to sum it up, yes.

Comment: intresting, let's give it a try ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already noticed, the main issue here is that `top` with percentage values will **only** work if the parent has a height specified which is not the case here. So in order to fix this we need to find a way to give the `item` a specified height equal to its content height and different from `auto`.

And idea would be to consider another `div` within the `#item` and make this one a flex container. This will make the new `div` to be stretched and have a height specified *(yes flex is magic)* thus the `top` value on the `img` will work fine.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #cfc;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#item {
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  animation: change-1 1s linear infinite alternate;
}

#item img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  animation: change-2 1s linear infinite alternate;
}


@keyframes change-1 {
  from {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
  }
  to {
    top:100%;
    left:100%;
  }
}
@keyframes change-2 {
  from {
    top:0%;
    left:0%;
  }
  to {
    top:-100%;
    left:-100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">
    <div>
      <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice! So to just be clear, you just added `display:flex` and one more `<div>` wrapping the content?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol yes that's it ;)

Comment: Fantastic! I will need to do a bit of tweaking to the system to add this new container (I like `>` combinators a little too much, so an extra layer breaks it!) but this will mean I can get rid of the JS "fix" and the corresponding FOUC-like jump.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol maybe in the meantime I will find another one without conainer, but the only solution I found without container works only with chrome, it rely on `min-content`/`max-content` defined as the height value of it, this will also break the height auto and we will have a height specified also

Comment: One thing I'm also having to account for is the "phantom" scrolling that appears because the "real" position is overflowing. I can't use `overflow:hidden` in this case because of other things going on, but I'm going to use `transform:translate(-100%,-100%)` (which will be integer-valued) and shift the other way.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol you can simply use `overflow: hidden;` on the container, no? it will hide all kind of internal overflow

Comment: Sadly not, there are custom tooltips that need to be able to go beyond the container.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use `transform` property to the placeholder and give value to x and y coordinates the same i.e -80%.  Hope this helps you out.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
#item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 80%;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
#item>img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: translate(-80%,-80%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have listed this as a "thing I tried" - `transform` is what I was using yesterday, but the problem with it is that it doesn't round to the nearest pixel as `position` does, and this results in blur on things like borders and images. Specifically I have pixel-based sprites and so blur like that just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a height of the parent element :)

---

**UPDATE**
You can also try to set for your `img` a negative `margin-top: -80%` instead of `top: 80%`, and set the `margin-bottom: 80%` to preserve parent element height:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #cfc;
}
#item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 80%;
  top: 80%;
  background-color: #fcc;
}
#item>img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  left: -80%;
  margin-top: -80%;
  margin-bottom: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The only trick is that margin in percents is setting relative to the parent element width, so, obviously, if you will have not square image, it will work incorrectly.

Comment: What part of "arbitrary" was unclear? :p The height of the parent element must fit whatever contents it is given.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol without any height set the ```position: relative; top: <everything>``` won't work

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol *withour any parent element height set, I mean)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I have edited my answer, check it out :)

Comment: Unfortunately your update only works for square images. `margin-top: <percentage>` is relative to the parent's *width*, not height. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have "resolved" the issue by having JavaScript set `margin-left` and `margin-top` based on the pixel size of the content, and added event handlers for the window resizing and the content changing. While this works, I don't like it. A CSS-only solution would trump this by far.